# Selenide: случайные ошибки при автотестировании

Tags: java, selenium

Всем доброго времени суток!

Занимаюсь разработкой автотестов для динамически генерируемого сайта с помощью Selenide и столкнулся со следующей проблемой: периодически тот или иной элемент отрабатывает некорректно (то дату криво запишет, то галочку пропустит или нажмет дважды и т.д.). Предсказать как-то данное поведение не представляется возможным. В итоге тест отрабатывает лишь с 3-4 попытки.

Кто-то встречался с подобной проблемой и есть ли какие-то пути решения?

Comment: потому что Selenide через одно место работает. я бы посоветовал отказаться и использовать Selenium webdriver

Comment: а по какому By ищешь элемент?

Comment: все сталкиваются с этим. интеграционные тесты на Selenide "хрупкие" и часто падают. попробуйте phantomjs.

Comment: @SeniorPomidor xpath

Comment: @ArtemiyIvanov видимо, у вас пути едут каждый раз

Answer (score 0):

Привет!

Это совершенно обычная ситуация. Почти у всех так и бывает. Это называется flaky test. Проблема не в Selenium и уж тем более не в Selenide. Проблему в том, что современный веб динамический: приложения отрисовывают разные кусочки с разной скоростью независимо друг от друга. И нужно свои тесты писать так, чтобы они были устойчивы к подобным неопределённостям.

В общем, без конкретных примеров и кусков кода тут не ответить.